# How do I switch to only using a keyboard for input?

Tags: keyboard, hotkeys, text-manipulation

Not sure if this in on topic here. I'm trying to completely switch to keyboard, yet, there is one main task I cannot achieve: to copy text from browsers and almost any program that is not a text editor.

Is there any trick for copying lines from programs, *for example this line in the post*, just using the keyboard? And is there a way to jump to a particular line too?

Answer (score 1):

### There's two types of solutions available;

- Application-specific:

web browsers:

In Firefox, you can select text in
three ways; using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+arrow key, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + f key, then entering the text string you wish to select, or <kbd>Tab</kbd>/<kbd>Shift</kbd> tab (one is cycling forward, the other cycles backwards). You would then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> key to copy your selected text. Finally <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste the text.

Other applications:

The list is endless, you just need to see what their hotkeys are and adjust those as you see fit. Every application will be different.

- System-wide:

Voice recognition app

[Mouse Keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mouse_keys)

Files:

convert the text you want to manipulate to another file type that is able to be modified by just a keyboard. If you're using a
unix-alike operating system this is very easy. Most files on UNIX are
plaintext files. Other file formats can be converted to plaintext.
You can then edit, copy, append, and manipulate the text however you
want using a shell emulator. Something similar can be done using MS Windows Machines using a shell emulator program (BASH on Windows, or Powershell depending on what version of MS Windows you are using.)

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>F7</kbd>, then you enable to move over the page with the keyboard.
That is called *[caret browsing](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/navigate-microsoft-edge-with-your-keyboard/)*

Answer (score 0):

On most OS's, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is the keyboard shortcut for copying. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+ one of the arrow keys will select from the cursor word by word in the direction of the arrow key. Just shift will select character by character. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> pastes whatever is in the keyboard. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> or <kbd>Down</kbd> selects a paragraph up or down.

Selecting would be pretty difficult using just the keyboard. I would select everything, paste into a text editor, and then delete everything you don't want.

Hope this helps!